# Why does this association work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a small app that allows users to upload recipes and save favourite recipes. I have a separate model called country that has all the countries of the world within it which then allows users to select one from a dropdown.

Initially I had the association as

recipe

```
has_one :country
```

country

```
belongs_to :recipe
```

After some research the correct association is

recipe

```
belongs_to :country
```

country

```
belongs_to :recipe
```

The foreign key country_id going within the recipe model.

I'm going to do some more reading but was wondering if someone could explain as to why it is this association and not the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guest you want to build association like this:

- country can has many recipe
- recipe belongs to one country

If so, you should define association is:

country:

```
has_many :recipes
```

recipe:

```
belongs_to :country
```

And i think your second association is also incorrect.

When you define `belongs_to :country` in Recipe model, it means your Recipe table must have a column called `country_id`. It is a foreign key to Country model.

In the first define association, the `Country` model will have a column called `recipe_id`, so, every country just has only one recipe, that's not what you want, right? Why it's not work? Because with one country you have only one record, so one country can have only one recipe, accessed through `recipe_id`.

With first association, your association is **One-to-One** (One Country has one Recipe), while you actually want your association is **One-to-Many** ( One Country has Many Recipe). So it's reason why first association not works (second too).

The main thing you need to remember here is, what model you put a `belongs_to` association, that model will have a column called `'association name'_id`. The different between using `has_one` and `belongs_to` only is **where you put foreign key** and **the meaning of association**. Check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one) to clearer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, and yes i want to be able to specify the same country for multiple recipes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the right association. The belongs_to association is always used in the model that has the foreign key (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)). Having foreign keys in both tables is not a good idea, as far as I can think. Can you explain why you think the last association is correct?

BTW, I think that the correct association is:
country has_many recipes and recipe belongs_to country

Comment: Well i initially started out with has_one :country in the recipe model but after asking questions this solution worked for me, the reason i think the last association works is that it works within the app. however i want to understand it, and maybe thats why i don't as its incorrect?

Comment: I can't tell why this is working. As far as I can tell writing country belongs_to recipe is wrong. If I understand the model correctly, each recipe can reference only a single country, while each country may have many recipes. The standard way to model that in rails would be the one I've described above.

Comment: yes your way does make more sense and i can understand that. i will change it later and see if still works, though im guessing there will be no problems, what i havent tested and it seem like it will fail is that if i create 2 recipes from the same country